# UIView layout Localization using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, autolayout

I would like to make an app using autolayout, such that when a device is configured in a right-to-left (RTL) language, the NSLayoutConstraints reverse the order of two views. I'm building the views programatically, without Interface Builder.

I am using leading and trailing constraints, and expect view A to be on the left and view B to be on the right. Once in RTL, I expect that order to be reversed, so that A is to the right of B.

I have added the RTL language to the localization list in the project Info tab.

Maybe I'm missing some project configuration. Where do I need to add the RTL language so that the project switches its layout according to the device language?

Note - I did try to change the "Localization native development region" in the Info.plist from "en" to an RTL language, and the constraints flipped. But this is not a solution because in this case it will always be flipped, even if the device language is in english.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of iOS are you developing against?

Comment: I believe automatically flipped layout for RTL languages did not appear until iOS 9

Comment: I am not looking for automatic flip. I manually wrote NSLayoutConstrains using the leading and trailing NSLayoutAttributes (which work correctly).
I am looking for the project to recognize that the device is in RTL mode, and make the constraints take that into account, so that the result will be a flipped view.

Comment: I'll rephrase the question to make it clearer.

Comment: That's a great question, hopefully someone can enlighten us with a solution.

Comment: Are you running this app in the simulator? Or on a device? What language is the simulator/device set to?

Comment: iPad running iOS 8.3.. and changed the language from english to hebrew.